# Query issue using OR and AND within the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am looking to create a simple query that shows all the products where the category ID matches the 'category' or 'category_2' columns within the database whilst matching the brand.

I need to have OR and AND being used within the same query.

This is my current query that works fine:

```
$all="SELECT * FROM models WHERE category = " . $category['id'] . " AND brand = ". $brand_name['id'] ." ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC";
```

This what I'm attempting to achieve:

```
$all="SELECT * FROM models WHERE category = " . $category['id'] . " OR category_2 = " . $category['id'] . " AND brand = ". $brand_name['id'] ." ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC";
```

However with the new query I made the AND brand section does not function.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: `WHERE categoryID IN (category, category_2) ... `

Comment: @tereško not if it not user input but a result of a previous select.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @vaso123 that just make is a little tiny bit harder to perform the injection.

Comment: @vaso123 I already have a prepared query that selects the ID from the category table... $category['id'] is a selected value from this prepared statement, does that mean I am safe from injection with the query shown in my question ?

Comment: @cousbrad as the others sad, always use prepared statements or at lease a `mysqli_real_escape_string` (if you are using mysqli) to be sure you are safe. if somebody changes that code, it could be vulnerable. I am told it to tresko theoratically.

Comment: @vaso123 Do you know how to inject a website, I only ask, as I believe my site is safe, and would like it checked by someone, would you mind trying to inject it just innocently (not messing up the site) to see any weak points ?

Comment: There are very good tutorials on the net. If you are using your own framework or no framework, the best way if you get a popular DBLayer or write your own. Just search for sql injection term, and PHP Database layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your logic:

```
$all="SELECT * FROM models 
WHERE (category = " . $category['id'] . " OR category_2 = " . $category['id'] . ")
AND brand = ". $brand_name['id'] ." ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC";
```

Answer (score 4):

This is prone to sql injection you should be using mysqli. Try this way:

```
$query = "SELECT column1,column2,column 3 FROM models WHERE (category = ? OR categeory_2 = ?) AND brand_name = ? ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$category['id'],$category['id'],$band_name['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col1);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `()`

```
$all="SELECT * 
FROM models 
WHERE (category = " . $category['id'] . " OR category_2 = " . $category['id'] . ")
AND brand = ". $brand_name['id'] ." 
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is place brackets around the OR conditions.

```
$all="SELECT * FROM models WHERE (category = " . $category['id'] . " OR category_2 = " . $category['id'] . ") AND brand = ". $brand_name['id'] ." ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

just put your `or` condition inside the `brackets` so they are groped and can be treated as a single condition then `AND` with second condition

```
$all="SELECT * FROM models 
WHERE (category = " . $category['id'] . " OR category_2 = " . $category['id'] . ")
AND brand = ". $brand_name['id'] ." ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC";
```